# Flutter Different Color for each Chip inside a Wrap Widget

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout, flutter-dependencies

I have 4 chips inside a wrap widget and the amount of the chips are based on the answers length so 4 chips, because thats the length of the answers, so i need instead of creating for chips and for each one to give a background color, i want to give the colors without creating for of them, right now i have created the chip and it displays according to the length, the list of chips are verticaly, so for the 1st chip the color is gonna be Color(0xFFEF6E98), for the 2nd Color(0xFFFFB139), for the 3rd Color(0xFF0A869B) and for the 4th Color(0xFF50CFFD).

Here is the code for the chip

```
child: Chip(
                                backgroundColor: Colors.blue, // hardcoded color
                                label: Container(
                                  width: 80.w,
                                  height: 11.3.h,
                                  child: Align(
                                    alignment: Alignment.topCenter,
                                    child: Text(
                                      answersText,
                                      style: GoogleFonts.fredokaOne(
                                        textStyle: TextStyle(
                                            fontSize: 20.0.sp,
                                            color: Colors.white),
                                      ),
                                      textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                                    ),
                                  ),
                                ),
                              )
```

Answer (score 0):

```dart
Wrap(
                                    direction: Axis.horizontal,
                                    children: List.generate(widget.targetSet.length, (index) => Container(
                                      height: 50,
                                      width: ((MediaQuery.of(context).size.width-100)/4),
                                      decoration: BoxDecoration(
                                        color: darken(Color.red,(index*0.1),
                                        border:   Border.all(width: 1,color: Color.green),
                                      ),
                                    )
                                    )
                                ),
```

Use Above code while creating the Wrap.

```dart
    Color darken(Color color, [double amount = .1]) {
  assert(amount >= 0 && amount <= 1);

  final hsl = HSLColor.fromColor(color);
  final hslDark = hsl.withLightness((hsl.lightness - amount).clamp(0.0, 1.0));

  return hslDark.toColor();
}
```